# Is it possible to always allow a program past Interactive Service Detection?

Tags: windows-7, windows

Is it possible to mark a program as "always okay to access the desktop" (or something) so that Windows doesn't constantly throw a Interactive Services Detection message?

Comment: Are you the Administrator over the computer in question?  Try the following tips and update your question http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/interactive-service-detection/1cbbf85d-dfa5-40b8-be04-c08034fbb32a

Comment: @Ramhound yes - to clarify this is just a single computer, and I want to allow the messages. Not just ignore Interactive Services. (In case that was unclear)

Comment: Have you determined which one of your services causes this message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this happens is because of the session separation for Services since Vista.

Services exist in Session 0, and all logins begin in Session 1.  This prevents things in the user session from being able to jump into a system-level service process within the same session.

This is known as a "[Shatter Attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shatter_attack)".

Since you'd be working exactly against a core security feature of Windows, I'd say no there's no way to do what you want (in Windows 7).

Instead, the real answer is to replace whatever service it is triggering the Interactive Services Detection with something that's been made with Vista+ in mind; something that doesn't expect the user session to be in the same session as the service.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, sometimes.  As a long term solution, Techie007 is correct and you should get a new service / support package.  Kludgy workarounds do exist.

If you have control over how the GUI portion of your service starts, for example if you are using srvany as a wrapper, you can then use something like PsExec to force the GUI into another session, bypassing the Interactive Service Detection.  Usually you would want to move the GUI into session 1, but not always.